# Quickly Launch application by pressing Windows Key and start typing app Name

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Until recently, I was able to launch applications quickly by bringing up that start menu in Windows 10 by pressing the Window key, and then I would start typing the name.  Windows seemed to automatically search for my application (or give me a suggestion on how to download it).  For example, if I wanted to launch Firefox, I would hit the Windows keyand when the start menu opened, I would type "fire" and hit enter when the Firefox application was selected.  This still works on my laptop, but on my desktop when I open up the start menu, it doesn't seem to be taking in what I am typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Windows 10 initial repairs.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run in order:

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Allow to finish, restart and test.

If this fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

One of the two fixes should repair this.

Failure of the above indicates the need to replace the User Profile, or back up and reinstall Windows. The latter is likely easier.

Comment: tried both and neither worked (although the "repair" did find some corrupt files, so uploading for that!)

Comment: You may at this point, need to back up the machine and reinstall Windows

Answer (score 0):

On your desktop computer, is Cortana turned off?
I was experiencing the same issue and turning Cortana on fixed it for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?